# Configure a webservice as subdirectory of a domain hosted in a different server

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I have a website with an hosted domain `https://www.somesamplesite.com` in a PC **(A)** with local network IP `192.168.1.10` and a service running on a different server hosted in a different PC **(B)** running at the address `192.168.1.25/myserver2` with no public domain.

Now I want that the service on **(B)** works as subdirectory of the website hosted in **(A)** so that if access
`https://www.somesamplesite.com/mysubdirectory` it works using the public domain of **(A)** at `mysubdirectory`

What is the configuration should I use to do this correctly?

Comment: The correct jargon for that is to configure the “mysubdirectory” locatyas a reverse proxy using for instance the ProxyPass directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On host A:

```
ProxyPass        /mysubdirectory/ https://192.168.1.25/myserver2/
ProxyPassReverse /mysubdirectory/ https://192.168.1.25/myserver2/
```